# Kendo Grid UI update is not calling the action in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-grid

When I use update dataSource from my kendo grid ui in asp.net core the update method is not getting called in my controller.

Here my kendo grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<StudentInfoViewModel>()
        .Name("kendoGrid#=CourseId#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Title("name");
            columns.Bound(o => o.Grade).Title("Grade");
            columns.Bound(o => o.Age).Title("Age");
            
        })
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Field(p => p.Name).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(p => p.Grade).Editable(true);
                    model.Id(p => p.StudentIdData);
                    model.Field(p => p.Age).Editable(false);
                    model.Id(p => p.CourseId);
                })
                .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home").
                    Type(HttpVerbs.Post));
        }
```

and this is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        StudentInfoViewModel studentInfoViewModel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(studentInfoViewModel);
        return NoContent();
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: This line of code is interesting:
`columns.Command(command => {command.Custom("Edit").Click("() => { Update('#=CourseId#'); }");})`.

It looks like it's calling a javascript function called `Update`. Is this function actually being called and could you add this function to your post?

Comment: it's just a simple function that logs something and I forgot to delete this line from my question – @ShawnOrr